# React compose prevent div wrap

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a simple component in React:

```
const applyFallbackStyles = withFallbackStyles( ( node, ownProps ) => {
  const { imageWidth } = ownProps;
  const divNode = node.querySelector( '.text' );
  return {
    fallbackImageWidth: getComputedStyle( divNode ).width,
  };
} );


class Image extends Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( ...arguments )
    }

    render() {
       <div className="test">Hello world</div>
    }
 }
```

and using compose to wrap a function

```
export default compose( [
    applyFallbackStyles,
] )( Image );
```

The component renders:

```
<div>
   <div className="test">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Why were there extra divs added? `compose` seems to by wrapping `<div className="test">Hello world</div>` in another `<div>`

Is it possible to avoid that? Or at least specify a class name for it.

Comment: Which `compose` function are you referring to? From Recompose, or Redux?

Comment: It is just a package with a collection of Higher Order Components. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/compose

Comment: And I am using this HOC https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/higher-order/with-fallback-styles

Answer (score 2):

as I understand from the source code of that lib, you will need to specify a node reference as props to your component otherwise it will add div by default. To avoid that maybe you can do like this

1)wrap your component by a div and get ref from that elemen

2)set that element as node props for the image element

```
class App extends React.Component{
  node = null;
  render() {
    <div ref={el => this.node = el} className="test">
      <Image node={this.node} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried but it is still adding the divs. `this.node` seems to be returning div test and everything in it. I am guessing that is was is expected?

Comment: Do you have running version somewhere to look at?

Comment: Please see updated code. I added the `applyFallbackStyles` function which I am using to grab a style property value. I do not have a running version

Comment: can you post your fullcode of your component here? I tried using the lib but I got regeneratorRuntime undefined